# Inject a formcontrol into a custom directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I want to create a directive can change a host element when a form control invalid as code sample below:

```
<div [appFormControlValidate]="email"> <!-- email is the form control I want to inject -->
  <input type="email" formControlName="email" />
</div>


@Directive({
  selector: '[appFormControlValidate]'
})
export class FormControlValidateDirective {
  @Input('appFormControlValidate') formControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.formControl); // <-- give me undefine
  }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Properties with `@Input` decorator will be accessible at the `OnInit` lifecycle, not in the *constructor*. When the property with `@Input` is initialized, the `OnChanges` event is called. At this time the property has the passed value and after this event `OnInit` is called once. So already at `OnInit` you will receive the passed value.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFormControlValidate]'
})
export class FormControlValidateDirective {
  @Input('appFormControlValidate') formControl: FormControl;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log(this.formControl);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right, it works like charm. Now I face another problem: how can I detect changes from the form control inside my directive.

Comment: You can listen for the Input changes in the OnChanges lifecycle event. But this will fire only if the reference of the input will be changed